Is every proper subspace of T. V. S. closed?
I know that every proper finite dimension subspace of T. V. S. Is closed.
And I also know that every proper subspace of of T. V. S. is not open.
Does this imply that every proper subspace is closed?

Finite sequences are dense in $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$

No. For example, if you consider the space $(C([a,b]),||\cdot||_{\infty})$, this normed space has a dense proper subspace (which can't be closed): the polynomials, as a consequence of Weierstrass approximation theorem.
Another example would be $(L^p(\mathbb{R}^N),||\cdot||_p)$ and the subspace $C_c(\mathbb{R}^N)$ (Brezis, theorem 4.12)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem
